# Perform task on opening the site

Tags: 7, users

I'm new to writing modules.

I would like my custom module to perform a task whenever the main page is loaded and no user is logged in, like when a user enters the url to my page, then the page loads and does something. I searched for a while now, but can't find the hook for this

What i tried was this:

```
function mymod_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['/'] = array('page callback' => 'mymod_do_it');

  return $items;
}
```

But this does not work. At the moment despair is joining me with this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: what do you mean by 'this does not work'.  does the callback get called? does your mymod_menu() get called?  I believe the path must exist in order to assign in this fashion, since you can't assign a page / , I suspect that is why its failing.  try creating a node, assigning it to the front page, and then use that node address in your menu assignment, not the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out the 'Examples for Developers' project page for some relevant examples:
https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

I think you want to use hook_init instead of hook_menu. Try this:

```
function mymod_init() {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()){
    $items = array();

    $items['/'] = array('page callback' => 'mymod_do_it');

    return $items;
  }
}
```